# Redux nested objects as state - is this possible/optimal

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm new to Redux so please bear with me. I am wondering if something like the following is possible and/or optimal and if so, how do you update the nested object values in the reducer?

```
const initialState = {
  banner: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    text: 'Some Title',
    textColor: 'white',
    image: null
  },
  nav: {
    mainOpen: false,
    authOpen: false,
  }

  ...
}
```

And then in a reducer something like this does not seem to work...

```
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  const {type, data} = action;
  switch (type) {
    case SET_BANNER_TEXT:
      return {
        ...state,
        banner.text: data //<-- ****THIS FAILS WITH UNEXPECTED TOKEN!!!****
      }

    ...
}
```

Or is it better to to have a 'banner' reducer, a 'nav' reducer and so on??

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're updating a key of an object, try using this to update the key

```
const state = {
  ...initialState,
  banner: {
    ...initialState.banner, // extend
    text: 'newText'
  }
}
```

which translates to

```
var state = _extends({}, initialState, {
    banner: _extends({}, initialState.banner, {
        text: 'newText'
    })
});
```

in ES5

check this [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/xunihihodu/edit?js,console)

**edit:** as stated in the comment below, it will overwrite the whole banner object if the code is used above. You can try the other answer in this thread using the `Object.assign()` and clone the `banner` object. If you still want to use spread operators, I updated my answer.

I think it is also better to have specific reducers for deeply nested state.And I will write it something like this

```
export function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
    case SET_BANNER_TEXT:
    case SET_BANNER_BG:
        return Object.assign({}, state,
            {
                banner: bannerReducer(state.banner, action)
            }
        );
    // ...
    default:
        return state;
    }
}

function bannerReducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
    case SET_BANNER_TEXT:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {text: action.payload});
    case SET_BANNER_BG:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {backgroundColor: action.payload});
    // ...
    default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will overwrite all the other properties of banner. If you need to keep them use banner: {...initialState.banner, text: 'new text' }

Comment: @JHurrah thanks! forgot to take that into consideration. :) I'm too used to separating reducers that I rarely run into that overwriting problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit new to redux too, so I can't speak too much to 'best practice'.  I would lean towards a new reducer personally, since you have have specific actions like `SET_BANNER_TEXT` (color, img, etc?) that modify a specific portion of your state tree and nothing else.  Making your reducers simple by breaking them apart, (even if there are a lot of them), will make things easier to trace down the road.

Syntactically you could achieve what you're trying to do with something like:

```
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  const {type, data} = action;
  switch (type) {
    case SET_BANNER_TEXT:
      const newBannerState = Object.assign({}, state.banner, {text: data});
      return Object.assign({}, state, {banner: newBannerState});
}
```